# Python-Django-Heroku not able to locate images in heroku, images not visible

Tags: python, django, heroku

so I recently deployed my django/python website (that used sqllite as a database) to heroku which hosts websites for free, everything is functioning normally like when I used to run localhost in my browser, except that this project is using postgressql database with heroku and images aren't appearing on my website, I looked everywhere and I think it has to do with the uploads file in the database(the path of the image is still the same but the location of the image changed).

local host image link: "http://localhost:8000/image/download/uploads/products/white_shirt_MERETfT.jpg"
heroku image link: "https://supremelebanon.herokuapp.com/image/download/uploads/products/offwhite_shirt_tQWa19c.jpg"
it says image not found for when I load the website on heroku hosting.
Please anyone I'm still a newbie with heroku I dont really know how it works, if anyone can help it would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.
settings.py file:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'morrr7ht4t4m)j#%ws34ntr7mdq$pui)+uy2-#%tx^iznh_##6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['supremelebanon.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'store',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'store.middlewares.auth.auth_middleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'supremelebanon.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'supremelebanon.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = "/image/download/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

image part in index.html:

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% load cart %}
{% load custom_filter %}

{{customer}}
{% if request.session.customer %}
<!-- body -->

<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
<div class="row">

<!--filter-->

<div class="col-lg-3 mx-auto">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="/" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action ">All Products</a> <!-- GOTTA DO A DROPDOWN -->
       {% for category in categories %}
          <a href="/?category={{category.id}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action ">{{category.name}}</a>
       {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

<!-- all products -->
    <div id='products' class="col-lg-9 mx-auto">
        <div class="row mx-auto">
            {% for product in products %}
                <div class="card mx-auto mb-3" id="{{product.id}}" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this settings.py, before to test you can compare with your code and see the diferences

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'morrr7ht4t4m)j#%ws34ntr7mdq$pui)+uy2-#%tx^iznh_##6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['supremelebanon.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'store',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 # 'store.middlewares.auth.auth_middleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'supremelebanon.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'supremelebanon.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases
try:
  from projectname.local_settings.py import DATABASES
except:
   import dj_database_url  
   import dotenv
   DATABASES = {}
   DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
   STATICFILES_STORAGE =  'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
   SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True # [1]
   SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = "/image/download/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR

# Activate Django-Heroku.
#django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

and for your local_settings.py is:

```
import os
from projectname.settings import BASE_DIR

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

### A brief explanation

We have to add the whitenoise that allows you to serve files in production, and also if you notice, heroku uses postgres as a DB in production, so it is better to use that for production.

Comment: okay thank you for clarifying the problem, appreciate it!!